# Run only tagged testcases from testrunner

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I've created two tags in ReadyAPI: "Test" and "Stage". I've tagged two testcases with "Test" and one with "Stage".

When I launch testrunner I only would like to run testcase/s tagged with "Stage":
I add follow parameters:

```
"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-3.20.2\bin\testrunner.bat" -r -a -j -f${WORKSPACE} "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML "-EDefault environment" "-TTestCase Stage" C:\TestOfTags-readyapi-project.xml -Dreadyapi.skip.endpoints.checks=true
```

But my tagged testcase don't run.

```
ReadyAPI 3.20.2 TestCaseRunner Summary
Time Taken: 753ms
Total TestSuites: 1
Total TestCases: 0 (0 failed)
Total TestSteps: 0
Total Request Assertions: 0
Total Failed Assertions: 0
Total Exported Results: 0
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out myself:

1. Create, let's say a tag with name = exampleTest
2. Tag testcases that you want to run with "exampleTest"
3. In testrunner simply add: "-TTestCase exampleTest"
4. Done